# Data Exchange Framework Tenant Service: The requested document was not found

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I found the Data Exchange Framework Tenant Service useful for me on a project and started to research it as it is pretty new tool. But I faced an issue.

I have installed all Tenant Service packages according a documentation. But when I try to request the tenant service via `{hostname}/api/tenant` URL, I will get the `The requested document was not found` error (originally a list of available endpoints is expected).

After some investigation, I haven't found a registration of the route. Probably I missed something

Does anybody know where `/api/tenant` route is defined or why I get the error?

Comment: Please check article https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/def/21/data-exchange-framework/en/walkthrough--implementing-a-tenant-service-endpoint.html for more details.

Comment: I started my research from this article and  gone through it before adding the question.

Comment: {hostname} is Sitecore instance or Tenant Service?

Comment: @VladShpak {hostname} is Tenant Service

Comment: 1. Have you installed Data Exchange framework with Tenant Service provider on Sitecore instance? 2.Have you added connection string to Tenant Service to connect Tenant Service with Sitecore instance? 3. Have you created tenant with tenant service endpoints?

Comment: Yes, I run Tenant Service on Sitecore instance. I added the appropriate connection string to the config file. The host name is accessible. I added an endpoint in Sitecore, but it doesn't really matter, because when I request `/api/tenat` url, it should return a lest of endpoints, but this URL is not reachable which means that it breaks before it request any data from TS

Comment: To run some DEF pipeline via pipeline tenant service endpoint you have to call {tenantServiceHost}/api/tenantservice/?id=[pipeline tenant service endpoint id]

Comment: {tenantServiceHost}/api/tenant returns json of available pipeline tenant service endpoints. It's kind of metadata.

Comment: @VladShpak yes, but according the following documentation `https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/def/21/data-exchange-framework/en/tenant-service-api-reference.html` I also can run  `/api/tenant` for getting a lists all available endpoints for the configured tenant. Anyway `/api/tenantservice` returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenant Service is web service and should be installed separately of Sitecore instance.

Tenant Service communicates with Sitecore via connection string:

```
<add name="sitecore" connectionString="database=master;tenant id=[tenant id];host=[sitecore host];password=[sitecore password];user name=[sitecore user name];timeout=20" />
```

Sitecore requires DEF and Tenant Service provider being installed. Tenant Service provider for DEF extends DEF to communicate with Web Tenant Service.

Comment: Accepted it as a answer because I definitely don't have a separate Web Tenant Service installed. But the link for downloading a `Sitecore Data Exchange Framework Tenant Service 2.1.0 rev. 181113.scwdp.zip` package is not available on Sitecore site. It is known issue and will be solved soon.